Power BI issue refreshing BigQuery data sources. ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1160)
After installing the August version of Power BI Desktop, the following error appears whenever I try to refresh some BigQuery data sources:
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1160) Cannot enable SSL for the connection when connecting to a server that has not enabled SSL. If the server has SSL enabled, please check if it has been configured to use a SSL protocol version that is lower than what is allowed for the connection. The minimum SSL protocol version allowed for the connection is: TLS 1.2.

I tried to refresh after uninstalling and re-installing Power BI Desktop but without success.

I was able to solve it in either of these two ways:

Uninstall he August version and re-install the July version of Power BI. You can download it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-latest-update-archive?tabs=powerbi-desktop#july-2024-update-21319010
Or

Remove the parallel update:

File -> Options and settings -> Options -> Current File -> Data load -> Parallel loading of tables -> One (disable parallel loading)


The September release of Power Bi doesn't solve the issue, it is still necessary to choose one of the two possible solutions. It is a bug known to the Microsoft team that appears from the August version onwards.
